# how to swap values of two rows with single query in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database that contains single table and I want to swap two rows with single sqlite query

I tried below query but this is not working in sqlite

```
UPDATE
rules AS rule1
JOIN rules AS rule2 ON
( rule1.rule_id = 1 AND rule2.rule_id = 4 )
SET
rule1.priority = rule2.priority,
rule2.priority = rule1.priority
;
```

anyone have done this task , please help me out

Comment: why single sql statement?

Comment: because this can be done using four queries and it takes very time thats why I need using single query, if you have solution then post here

Comment: use two: see http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/

Comment: of course the first one is a query for reading the initial values

Answer (score 1):

A query like this is syntactically valid, but will **not** work because the first row is updated before it is read for the second update:

```
UPDATE rules
SET priority = CASE rule_id
               WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT priority FROM rules WHERE rule_id = 4)
               WHEN 4 THEN (SELECT priority FROM rules WHERE rule_id = 1)
               END
WHERE rule_id IN (1, 4)
```

If your reason for wanting a single query is speed, just use a single transaction for all four statements; this is as fast as you can get:

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    long prio1 = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,
                    "SELECT priority FROM rules WHERE rule_id = " + 1, null);
    long prio4 = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,
                    "SELECT priority FROM rules WHERE rule_id = " + 4, null);
    db.execSQL("UPDATE rules SET priority = " + prio4 + " WHERE rule_id = " + 1);
    db.execSQL("UPDATE rules SET priority = " + prio1 + " WHERE rule_id = " + 4);
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: @CL your code is working , but thats only update one field, i want to swap all field value

Comment: @Jayesh So you want to swap *all* fields except `rule_id`?